# How to split at HTML entities

Tags: javascript, split, html-entities

How can I split the text in `<p>Hello&emsp;World!</p>` into `Hello` and `World`?

I tried:
`document.querySelector('p').innerHTML.split(/&emsp/);`

but it isn't working

Comment: Do you want to split only where this HTML entity was?, where any HTML entity was?, at any EM space character? For the two formers, that won't be easy since for the DOM tree, they never were HTML entities, the tokenizer did convert these sequence to the corresponding character directly and the Text token that the DOM parser already contained the final character.

Answer (score 1):

You can spilit it by with withspace `\s+`

```js
let txt = document.querySelector('p').innerHTML
data = txt.split(/\s+/)
console.log(data)
```

```html
<p>Hello&emsp;World!</p>
```

Comment: I doubt they'll have only this character as white-space. There are *great* chances that the <p>Hello&emsp;World!</p> was just a minimal, but non exhaustive example.

Answer (score -1):

Use replace method:

```
document.querySelector('p').innerHTML.replace(/&emsp;/,' ');
```

And If you need the data in array

```
const splitDataArr = document.querySelector('p').innerHTML.split(/\s+/);
```